# Primary key not updating automatically when using Django to insert into the DB

Tags: python, django

I have a postgres table:

```
                                                         Table "public.channels"
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('channels_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 area       | character varying(12)       | not null                                              | extended |              | 
 measure    | integer                     |                                                       
Indexes:
    "channels_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I can insert into this table using `psql`, and the `id` column, which I don't specify, increments each time.  I end up with several entries in the table.

I have this Django model for this table:

```
class Channels(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12, editable=True)
    measure = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.measure)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Channels'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'channels'
```

I am trying to insert like this:

```
area = 'site b'
for sample in samples:
    measure = sample['measure']

    ch = Channels(area=area, measure=measure)
    ch.save()
```

This inserts each measurement into the table.  But the primary key does not increment, and at the end, the last measurement is the only one in the table.  It has the data from the last `sample` from `samples`.

Why isn't the primary key incrementing automatically, so that each measurement goes into its own row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.

You have set `area` as your primary key, so Django is not updating it. I think rather than making `area` primary key, you can set it Unique like this:

```
area = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=12, editable=True)
```